# Error: ligo: generated. untyped BIG_MAP_EMPTY

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, ligo

In ligo for a smart-contract
I have a big_map in my storage and I want to pass nothing in the map as intial_storage value.

```
{
name = "stablecoin";
symbol = "eur";
total_supply = 1000n;
allow_transfer_from = Big_map.literal[(sender,{transfer_for = sender; amount = 10n})];
balances = Big_map.empty;
owner = sender;
tokens = 10000n;
}
```

In the above code when I pass some value in map `allow_transfer_from` it works but Big_map.empty `balances` doesn't work and produces the error:

```
Error: ligo: generated. untyped BIG_MAP_EMPTY
```

I am not able to find how to pass no value as initial storage in Big_Map.
If anyone has any ideas, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should type the `Big_map.empty`.
For instance (I do not know the type of your big map): `(Big_map.empty : (nat , token) big_map)`